# What softwares to make maps of linguistic,ethnic distribution, and also territorial division

Tags: cartography, software-recommendations, free-software

What softwares can I use to make maps of:

- ethnic distribution, very detailed map like this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Austria_Hungary_ethnic.svg
- Linguistic distribution (I cannot paste link here because not enough reputation).
- Territorial division (I cannot paste link here because not enough reputation).

I'm planning to make ethnic and linguistic distribution maps of South China region. I wonder if anyone of you, who is expert on map making, knows what kind of software (free softwares only) should I use to create such high quality and detailed maps for South China region. I would make them and then upload on Wikipedia.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. I'm afraid you're going to need to backtrack to do more research on what GIS is  before asking a question which would result in only a few paragraphs of response.  *Any* mapping package can make good maps with the right data, but obtaining that data could be a great deal of effort, and "high-quality" maps may not be possible for a novice. Please take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to better understand how to ask a question here.

Comment: What do you mean by that? do you mean that I'm posting on a wrong stackexchange site? But I notice that only GIS stackexchange is related about map. What site else can I post this ?

Comment: I have re-read your comment. You are talking about data? I already have data. You know what I mean. The only think I'm lacking is a software to make map.

Comment: We would need more information about the data you have and what format it is in to be able to offer any help. As Vince mentioned, pretty much any GIS or mapping software can be used to create maps. High-quality is somewhat subjective and might require publication software like Adobe Illustrator in addition to the mapping software. The most common recommendation for free GIS software is likely to be [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/).

Comment: While GIS has significant overlap with cartography, they are not nearly the same thing. While you may have the latent talent to create high quality maps from as-yet-unnamed data, asking for GIS software in this context is equivalent to asserting that word processing software is the only thing lacking in creation of a Pulitzer-winning novel.

Comment: No, No, no ,no ,no, no,no,  my friendd. No one can do anything without learning, even with excellent talent. But map making is not a big deal, I can do googling and youtubing to get information or come here to ask people. Nothing difficult, you know what's I mean?

Comment: @Chris W: My data is secret, cannot be shared.

Comment: If you cannot even describe the format of the data you have, then I'm afraid this question likely too broad for this site. As an aside, you mention creating maps and uploading them to Wikipedia. I would be highly skeptical of any such information uploaded without references or citation of sources, and might even expect it to be removed from Wikipedia. I also think you severely underestimate the effort required for cartography if you describe it as 'nothing difficult' and 'not a big deal'.

Comment: Oh my Gotttttttttttttttttttttttt. That is not true, my friendd. When I upload it to Wikipedia I will add necessary sources so that it won't be removed, right? your pessimism is making cartography very very difficult to you. But cartography is very interesting to me, so it makes difficulties become more interesting. Nothing difficult, you know what I mean ?

Answer (score 3):

[QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/) is free and open source GIS software that has all of the functionality you would need to create maps such as the one you link to. There are a wide variety of [QGIS tutorials](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/), although I would recommend the [Making a Map](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/making_a_map.html) tutorial in your case.

Additional Resources:

- [QGIS Training Manual](http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/)
- [Creating Maps](http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/map_composer/index.html)
- [QGIS - Map Showcase](https://www.flickr.com/groups/qgis/pool/)

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. I'm trying it now. When I get problem, I would come here and ask you, right?

Comment: You would want to open a new question. Best of luck!